# Error: File lib.dom.d.ts does not have a sourceFile

Tags: angular, webpack, sentry

I am using angular(7) cli for my app. I recently added sentry integration into the app and when I build prod I am getting an error:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@sentry/utils/esm/is.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: File lib.dom.d.ts does not have a sourceFile.
    at Object.getSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/helpers/transform-javascript.js:86:23)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87549:29)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:85
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87424:34)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:13)
    at processRootFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87287:13)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87763:21
    at Object.forEach (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:210:30)
    at processLibReferenceDirectives (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87758:16)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87598:17)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:85
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87424:34)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:13)
    at processRootFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87287:13)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:86300:60
    at Object.forEach (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:210:30)
[31mERROR in ./node_modules/@sentry/utils/esm/misc.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
Error: File lib.dom.d.ts does not have a sourceFile.
    at Object.getSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/helpers/transform-javascript.js:86:23)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87549:29)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:85
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87424:34)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:13)
    at processRootFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87287:13)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87763:21
    at Object.forEach (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:210:30)
    at processLibReferenceDirectives (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87758:16)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87598:17)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:85
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87424:34)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87457:13)
    at processRootFile (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:87287:13)
    at /Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:86300:60
    at Object.forEach (/Users/shurikag/PRIZ/dev/priz-fe/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:210:30)
```

What am I going wrong?
I didn't find anything on the web that directed me to the right direction.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Maybe it's a bug on their end?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downgrading to sentry 5.6.3 resolved the issue.

1. `npm uninstall @sentry/browser -S`
2. `npm install @sentry/browser@5.6.3 -S`

Comment: This actually solves the problem. Got it by accidentally updating `@sentry/browser`.